# How to get strnset working in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

Not sure what is necessary to get "strnset" to work in QT?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

---

```
char mouse[1000];
strnset(mouse,'\0', 1000);
```

---

and this will error out...

Comment: A quick google search leads me to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235495(v=vs.80).aspx which says `strnset` is deprecated for `_strnset` in header `<string.h>`.

Comment: With this level of detail all I can tell you is "try `memset` instead."  Qt is a third-party bolt-on which provides neither `<stdio.h>` nor `<string.h>`; to help you any further, we need to know the identities of your OS and compiler, and we need to see the error messages.

Comment: When you say it "errors out" what do you mean?  The computer reboots when you try to compile?

Comment: @MooingDuck As usual, whenever MSVC documentation says "[standard name] is deprecated in favor of [name that begins with an underscore]", *do not believe them*.  The kindest thing I can say about this attitude on MS's part is that it is based on a willful misinterpretation of the C(++) standards.

Comment: You can also use `std::fill_n` instead.

Comment: @Zack strnset doesn't seem to be a part of either the C or C++ standards. At least, it's not in any references I've checked.

Comment: @Slavik81 Yah, indeed it is not.  In fact, it isn't even POSIX.  (The authoritative list of POSIX+ISO `str*` functions may be found here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/string.h.html ) So the MSDN documentation linked above is doubly incorrect - in describing `strnset` as having been POSIX in the first place, as well as in declaring it deprecated "for compliance with ISO C++".  (There is no such compliance requirement; when applied to actual POSIX functions, the underscores serve only to make it harder to port code between Windows and Unix.)

Comment: what's wrong with `memset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strnset`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frtref%2Fstrnset.htm) is an extension to C, and will not be available on many compilers (I had never heard of it, actually). This has nothing whatsoever to do with Qt.

There are a few ways to accomplish this same effect in Qt, though. Take a look at the different options for [QByteArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html)

- Use the [QByteArray(size,ch)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-3) constructor which will repeat `ch` by `size` times
- Create a QByteArray containing only "\0", and using the [repeated](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#repeated) function to generate a QByteArray of 1000 \0s.
- Creating an empty QByteArray and using [setNum](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#setNum) looks like it would work

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to do this outside of the Qt classes, the C++ standard algorithm [std::fill_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) looks like it would do what you want.

Comment: Interesting, that according to your documentation, `strnset` was misused here.

Answer (score 2):

Available options:

1. Use [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/).
2. Use [`std::fill_n`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill_n/)
3. Use [`qFill`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qFill-2)
4. Use [`QVector<char>`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html) it has [`fill`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html#fill) method.
5. (assuming you don't need "char", but a string) [`QString s = QString(1000, QChar('a'))`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#QString-5);
6. (Assuming you need buffer): [`QByteArray`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html).